# Camera frozen after capture, OnpictureTaken method never called

Tags: android, camera, image-capture

I am working on an application which uses the camera to capture images. I am using callback methods for capture. It's working normally in all devices except **"Huawei MediaPad 7inch"**,which has **android 4.0.3**. When i am launching my camera, after capturing image the camera freezes and OnPicturetaken method never called. In log cat I got the camera error **"E/Camera(4562): Error -2147483648"** Please help.
Here is my code.

```
public void takePicture() {
    try {
        Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallbackRaw = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera c) {
                /** Do nothing */
            } 
        };

        Camera.ShutterCallback mShutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
            public void onShutter() {
                /** Do nothing */
            }
        };

        mPreview.mCamera.takePicture(mShutterCallback, mPictureCallbackRaw, this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        NGAndroidUtil.logErr("[CameraPreview] takePicture exception", ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should report this bug to Huawei corp.